Definite Integral doesn't return results
MMA cannot integrate this function:
Integrate[1/(1 + (x + Tan[x])^2), {x, -Infinity, +Infinity}] // FullSimplify

Neither do a few other sites on the net which normally can do well.
Is there a way to do this? Do we need to break the function to pieces then integrate the components seperately?
Thanks
P.S. NIntegrate returns 2.46004 for it which is also strange as the expression is supposed to resolve to π
Also note if we sub for Cot, MMA gives a different value:
NIntegrate[
 Cot[x]^2 / (Cot[x]^2 + x^2*Cot[x]^2 + 2 x*Cot[x] + 
    1), {x, -Infinity, +Infinity}]

---> 2.9794
The graph does not look very extraordinary, why is this not solvable by regular MMA integration.


How do you know "the expression is supposed to resolve to π" ?

if you run NIntegrate on it, as is with no options, you see it generated lots of Warnings about failed convergence, So result is not really numerically reliable. If you plot the integrand you can see why. Maple could not do this even numerically.

Doing something like the following gets you closer to $\pi$:  2 NIntegrate[1/(1 + (x + Tan[x])^2), {x, 0, \[Pi]/2}] + 2 Sum[NIntegrate[1/(1 + (x + Tan[x])^2), {x, \[Pi]/2 + (k - 1) \[Pi], \[Pi]/2 + k  \[Pi]}, WorkingPrecision -> 100], {k, 1, 1000}] // Quiet.

Hi @A. Kato : The problem asked for a proof that it equals π.

Hi @JimB:  your broken down intervals above over larger k iterations hits the nail on the head. Why would this work, and not the overall range in 1 shot?

Hi @Nasser:  mine is not returning any warning messages, should this not be ON by default?

mine is not returning any warning messages It could be you are using different version. I am using V 14.1, here is screen shot   https://i.sstatic.net/zbLROl5n.png

Ok mine is v14.0.0 and it seems that I needed to add the 2 CurrentValue's to my session and now I get the same.

If proof is needed, I think Mathematics SE rather than Mathematica SE is more appropriate.

@A.Kato  I agree would be valuable to post on Mathematics Stack Exchange.

I asked chatgpt and she recommended me to read this webpage: https://isolution.pro/de/q/ma14013260/ein-seltsames-integral-int-infty-infty-dx-over-1-left-x-tan-x-right-2-pi?utm_source=chatgpt.com

Every solution in the above link contains gaps or is outright wrong. I would not go into details, but, I think, MA assisted solution would be of great interest.

For a proof that this is equal to $\pi$, see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1015462.

This is an extended comment that supports the value of the integral value stated. Note  integrand is symmetric about $x=0$. In the following the tables are progressive partial sums
u[x_] := 1/(1 + (x + Tan[x])^2)
Plot[u[x], {x, 0, 41 Pi/2}, 
 GridLines -> {Table[Pi/2 + j Pi, {j, 0, 20}], None}, 
 GridLinesStyle -> Red, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, 
 PlotLabel -> Row[{"u(x)=", u[x]}]]

f[0] := NIntegrate[u[x], {x, 0, Pi/2},
  Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
f[n_] := 
 NIntegrate[u[x], {x, Pi/2 + (n - 1) Pi, Pi/2 + n  Pi}, 
  Method -> "LocalAdaptive"]
ac = Accumulate[Table[f[j], {j, 0, 1000}]];
ListPlot[ac, GridLines -> {None, {Pi/2}}, GridLinesStyle -> Red, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 2}, 
 PlotLabel -> HoldForm[Integrate[u[x], {x, 0, Infinity}]]]
acc = Table[{j, Pi/2 // N, Pi/2 - j // N, 1 - 2 j/Pi // N}, {j, ac}];
func[p_, q_] := 
 TableForm[acc[[p ;; q]], 
  TableHeadings -> {Range[p, q], {"Approximation", "\[Pi]/2", 
     "AbsoluteError", "Relative error"}}]
func[1, 10]
func[190, 200]
func[990, 1000]



An idea
I have deleted my attempt using complex analysis. It was completely wrong as alluded to by Ulrich and @yarchik. Live and learn.
@yarchik has provided a useful link in comments below. Thank you @yarchik.
Also see link from @pisco in comments below under the question.
This underlies neat proof.
Thank you again @yarchik and @pisco.

The inequality $|u(z)| \leq \left|\frac{1}{1+z^2}\right|$ is not true. Think of zeroes of $z+\tan z$, for example, $z=2.028757838110434...$. At this point the LHS is equal to one, but the RHS is equal  to 1/(1 + z^2) /. z -> 2.028757838110434 == 0.195471.

@user64494  You are correct as it was written.  It was meant to be supremum of  modulus of the function  to bound integral:  I note (as usual) you have down-voted the answer without allowing a user to explain or correct their error. I will not participate in a combative futile discourse I will delete  the speculative aspect of this post  & await other users who may provide an insightful answer. As you receive votes for answers that are incorrect failing to see that $\frac{\sqrt x}{\sqrt x}-1 =0$. Note I commented but did not down vote.

Both AsymptoticIntegrate[  1/(1 + (x + (n - 1)*Pi + Tan[x])^2), {x, 0, Pi}, {n, Infinity, 2}] and AsymptoticIntegrate[  1/(1 + (x + (n - 1)*Pi + Tan[x])^2), {x, 0, Pi}, {n, -Infinity, 2}] result in 1/(n^2 \[Pi]) in 14.1 on Windows. Therefore,  these asymptotics imply the convergence of the  integral under consideration .

If you expand in the neighborhood of a zero of x+tan(x) you’ll find that the denominator grows quite fast— you can bound the derivative from below by x^2. That might help to prove convergence, since you can then split into regions where the denom is large and, where it is small, you can show those regions have length decreasing sufficiently fast.

@user64494 What do the integrals AsymptoticIntegrate[...,n->Infinity] have to do with the original problem?

@UlrichNeumann; The aim of my comment is to prove the convergence of the integral under consideration Integrate[1/(1 + (x + Tan[x])^2), {x, -Infinity, +Infinity}] which is not obvious.

@ubpdqn Very interesting answer. I'm struggeling with the complex transformation of Tan[] I  would expect p=(I (E^(-I z) - E^(I z)))/(E^(-I z) + E^(I z)), am I wrong?

@UlrichNeumann no you are correct. I was just “generalizing”: from case $|z|=1$. Change the usual $\tan$ we are used to all the plane: like $ \cos(z) =\frac{z+1/z}{2}$. I may have blundered and just got right answer by chance. Note if you  scale $z= r \exp(i \theta), r>0$, the $r$ cancels out and you get your expression.

Have a look at the solutions here. Maybe you can use them as a starting point of your MA-assisted proof?

@yarchik thank you very much! That is very nice. I’ll delete that section with a comment. The link you provide will be most useful.

Adapt precision and do the sum over the periods of $\tan$
 (NIntegrate[1/(1 + (x  + Tan[x])^2), {x, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}] + 
   2 Sum[NIntegrate[
   1/(1 + (x + k \[Pi] + Tan[x])^2), 
     {x, -(\[Pi]/2), \[Pi]/2}, 
            WorkingPrecision -> 128, PrecisionGoal -> 12 , 
                 MaxRecursion -> 20], 
    {k, 1, 160}] // Quiet)/\[Pi]

   0.997471

Edit: Sums and integrals of measurable functions are exchangeable:
   Sum[1/(1 + (k \[Pi] + x + Tan[x])^2), {k, -\[Infinity], \[Infinity]}]

$$\frac{1}{2} (\coth (i x+i \tan (x)+1)+\coth (-i x-i \tan (x)+1))$$
 NIntegrate[Re[Coth[1 + I x + I Tan[x]]], {x, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, 
   MaxRecursion -> 64, PrecisionGoal -> 10, WorkingPrecision -> 22]/\[Pi] //
   Quiet

   0.9999994225701138587250

It's possible to get more exact results numerically:
Plot[Re[Coth[1 + I x + I Tan[x]]], {x, -(\[Pi]/2), \[Pi]/2}]


NIntegrate[Re[Coth[1 + I x + I Tan[x]]], {x, -\[Pi]/2, \[Pi]/2}, 
  Method -> "LocalAdaptive" ]/\[Pi] // Quiet

1.

and, of course without Mathematica
Herglotz Trick
$$\pi \cot ( \pi x) =  \lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{-n}^n \ \frac{1}{x+n} = \frac{1}{x} \ + \ 2 x\ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{x^2-n^2}$$
$$\int \cosh(1+ix) \ i\ dx = \int \frac{\cosh(1+i x)}{\sinh (1+ i x)} \ i \ dx \ = \ \log \left(\sinh (1 + i x)\right) $$

A spot on the Sun:  0.997976087776902 for {k, 1, 200}, i.e.  slow convergence of the sum.

@RolandF useful further evidence and like update

@RolandF Very clever answer! Still I'm struggeling. Mathematica 12.2 gives an answer  (I (PolyGamma[0, -(I/\[Pi]) + z/\[Pi] + Tan[z]/\[Pi]] -     PolyGamma[0, I/\[Pi] + z/\[Pi] + Tan[z]/\[Pi]]))/(2 \[Pi]) . How did you transform to Coth[...]?

Vs 14 yields $$\sum _{k=-\infty }^{\infty } \frac{1}{(\pi  k+x)^2+1}=\frac{1}{2} (\coth (1+i x)+\coth (1-i x))$$

Have a look at the solutions here. Maybe you can use them as a starting point of your MA-assisted proof?

In my opinion, @ubpdqn rejected his nice complex analysis to early.
If we try to apply residue theorem in the lower half circle( R->Infinity) we first have to find the pols of 1/(1 + (z + Tan[z])^2) in this region
solz = NSolve[0 == 1 + (z + Tan[z])^2 && -10 < Re[z] < 10 && -10 < Im[z] <  10, z,Complexes] 
pol = Select[z /. solz, Im[#] <= 0 &]
(*{-1.98423 - 0.154336 I, 0. - 0.521298 I, 1.98423 - 0.154336 I}*)

The residue are zero at these points:
Map[Residue[1/(1 + (z + Tan[z])^2), {z, #}] &, pol] (*{0,0,0}*)

That's why it is sufficient to integrate over the half circle to get Integrate[1/(1 + (x + Tan[x])^2),{x,-Infinity,Infinity}]
AsymptoticIntegrate[1/(1 + (z + Tan[z])^2) /. z -> R Exp[I t], {t, 0, -Pi}, R -> 0] 
(* -Pi *)

result:


thanks for posting
